# Why we overriding the bootstrap in bower.json

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I am having some issue with including bootstrap. Why we are trying to override the bower.json with bootstrap? Here is the code

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "less/bootstrap.less"
      ]
    }
  }
```

What is the use for the override? Is this correct way?

Other way I found is including in stylesheet like `@import "../../bower_components/file"`. but it is not a good practice.

Is there any other way to include?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `directory` property of the config to change the path where everything gets saves:
https://bower.io/docs/config/

.bowerrc

```
{
    "directory": "assets/vendors",
}
```

This way you can include bootstrap in you CSS like the following

```
@import '../vendor/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css'
```

Assuming you file structure like similar to this one:

```
/assets/css/styles.css
/assets/js/scripts.js
/assets/vendors/bootstrap
```

Comment: i don't want to import the file in CSS and my `bootstrap` package is inside `bower_components/bootstrap`. ' .bowerrc' Is completely new for me. any other way?

Comment: What is your desired goal?
Include bootstrap's CSS and JS via the `link` and `script` tag or what is your intension?

Comment: When i include other packages i am just injecting into module, But for bootstrap it is not working we have to override the `bower.json`. how can i inject the `bootstrap` package? Why we are overriding the `bootstrap` package in `bower.json`?